# Calling functions without names in Java

Tags: java, function

I have a set of similar classes that all implement a function of the form

```
public static ClassA convertToClassA(Obj A)

public static ClassB convertToClassB(Obj B)
```

I want to loop through a list of classes and call this function that takes one argument of `Obj` in each class. How do I do this given each function is named differently?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you please explain with code ? Now it's little fishy.

Comment: Read little bit more about Java reflection http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: Isn't that what an interface would be good for?

Comment: Can you elaborate? There are more than 20 such classes and I don't intend to change all of them.

Comment: @user592748. If you have more than 20 classes, how do you know what method to call? How do you know what a specific instance can convert to?

Comment: If you are going for a quick fix or refactoring is not an option because of the existing code base, you can create a mapping that tells you which method should be called on which class and call it using the reflection api, but this solution is quite hackish, you will sacrificing maintainability and readability. If it is possible and you will need to maintain this code for a long time, better consider refactoring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Class cls = Class.forName("ClassA");
String methodName = "convertTo" + cls.getSimpleName();
Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, new Class[]{Obj.class});
// If the underlying method is static, then the first parameter is ignored. It may be null as illustrated below. 
method.invoke(null, your_object);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create common interface with your method signature and let your invokable classes implement it, later on you can iterate over your objects as over instances of interface and call methods from it so no problem.
**HOWEVER** I am starting to think you want to call method without knowing it's name AT ALL - the only knowlage of target method is the number and type of arguments. Well that indeed IS impossible via reflection BUT, it will be innacurate if similar methods signatures will be present. Anyway, don't know what are you trying to do, but your project is badly designed from the ground (no interfaces, poor inharitance I guess etc.)

Comment: The interface won't help much if these are static methods.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the reflection package. it provide methods to get back all the methods an instance has provide.

The apache common's BeanUtil (http://commons.apache.org/beanutils) also provide some util method doing similar things.